# Python, how to make a function which takes a function as an argument along with two arrays?

Tags: python, generator

For learning purposes, I'm trying to make a function using Python that takes in another function and two arrays as parameters and calls the function parameter on each index of each array parameter. So this should call add on a1[0] & a2[0], a1[1] & a2[1], etc. But all I'm getting back is a generator object. What's wrong?

```
def add(a,b):
    yield a + b


def generator(add,a1,a2):
    for i in range(len(a1)):
        yield add(a1[i],a2[i])


g = generator(add,a1,a2)

print g.next()
```

I've also tried replacing what I have for yield above with

```
yield map(add,a1[i],a2[i])
```

But that works even less. I get this:

> TypeError: argument 2 to map() must support iteration

Comment: yield yields a generator object, it looks like you have a generator of generator, perhaps you just want to return the sum from add?

Comment: You already got the answer but you could also just do
`map(add,a,b)` or `(i+j for i,j in zip(a,b))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your definition of `add()` is at least strange (I'm leaning twoards calling it "wrong").  You should `return` the result, not `yield` it:

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b
```

Now, your `generator()` will work, though

```
map(add, a1, a2)
```

is an easier and faster way to do (almost) the same thing.  (If you want an iterator rather than a list, use `itertools.imap()` instead of `map()`.)

Comment: I can't believe I didn't know that map accepts multiple sequences like this-- it's even been in the tutorial for a decade.  Learn something new every day!

Answer (score 4):

You get a generator because your `add` is a generator. It should be just `return a + b`.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm trying to make **a function** using Python **that takes in another function and two arrays** as parameters **and calls the function parameter on each index of each array parameter**.

```
def my_function(func, array_1, array_2):
    for e_1,e_2 in zip(array_1, array_2):
        yield func(e_1,e_2)
```

Example:

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

for result in my_function(add, [1, 2, 3], [9, 8, 7]):
    print(result)
```

will print:

```
10
10
10
```

Now, a couple of notes:

- The `add` function can be found in the [`operator`](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html) module.
- You see that I used `zip`, take a look at its the [doc](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip).
  Even though what you actually need is [`izip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) the generator expression under `zip()` which basically doesn't return a list but an iterator to each value.
- `my_function` is almost like [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map), the only difference is that `my_function` is a generator while `map()` gives you a list. Once again the stdlib gives you the generator version of `map` in the [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) module: [`imap()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap)

Example, `my_fuction` is just like [`imap`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap):

```
from operator import add
from itertools import imap

for result in imap(add, [1, 2, 3], [9, 8, 7]):
    print(result)

#10
#10
#10
```

I obviously suppose that the `add` function was just a quick example, otherwise check the built-in [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sum).

Comment: OP's using Python 2 (the sample code includes a `print` statement)

Comment: @ChadMiller: I didn't notice that, thanks! I'll change the links :)

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you are defining `add` incorrectly and it should `return` instead of `yield`.  Also, you could import it:

```
from operator import add
```

The reason why this doesn't work:

```
yield map(add, a1[i], a2[i])
```

Is because `map` works on lists/iterables and not single values.  If `add` were defined correctly this could work:

```
yield map(add, [a[i]], [a2[i]])
```

But you shouldn't actually do that because it's more complicated than it needs to be for no good reason (as Sven Marnach's answer shows, your generator function is just an attempt to implement `map` so it really shouldn't use `map` even if it is a learning exercise).  Finally, if the point is to make a function that takes a function as a parameter, I wouldn't call the parameter "add"; otherwise, what's the point of making it at all?

```
def generator(f, a1, a2):
    for x, y in zip(a1, a2):
        yield f(x, y)
```

Speaking of which, take a look at [`zip`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip).